# Golang: how can filename arguments be parsed?

Tags: go

I am writing a command line utility in golang, which takes a file as an argument.  How can I accurately turn this argument into a useable file?  It seems there are many cases to handle:

- An absolute path has been given, and I should use it as is
- A relative path has been given, and I should path.Join() it with the current working directory
- "."'s and "../"'s are used in the path, and I believe I should still use path.Join() and Go will simplify the path?

Does Go provide anything to handle this?  Should I just branch based on whether the first character is '/'?  That seems like a hacky solution, but perhaps it always works and so should be done?

Comment: just use viper: github.com/spf13/viper

Comment: @fabrizioM that's *massive* overkill for a simple/trivial call to `os.Open`/`os.Create`.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system interprets paths for you. You don't need to do anything with path names. You can simply do something like this:

```
os.Open("./path/to/file")
os.Open("another/file")
os.Open("../some_file")
```

et cetera

Answer (score 0):

Taking aside that you don't want to see `.` as a file, there's not that much to worry about.

In a trusted environment*, where the user can indeed point to *any* file, the `os` package will take care of it. No need to `filepath.Join` anything.

- If an absolute path is given, it will open it. (i.e.: starting with `/`)
- If not, then it will see it relative to the current working directory. (including `.` and `./`)

---

(*) In a non-trusted environment (a web server for example), you will want to validate the path given for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

OS does hard work for you. However passed argument possible can correspond a directory. You should either check `os.FileInfo.IsDir`, or implement `path.filepath.WalkFunc()` taken by `path.filepath.Walk()` for batch operations. Latter is quite a common approach.